# Disabling CKEditor, Re-enabling with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, fckeditor

I have the following:
POST page that allows users to write text in CKEditor
VIEW Page, that views the text in CKEditor

How can I make CKEditor in the view page READ only, meaning the user can not edit the text in the note? The reason I want to use CKEditor in the view page is for 2 reasons:
1. I can use JavaScript to move the editor from disabled to enabled
2. Keep the styles the same from the POST & View page.

Is this possible? Thanks!

B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if you are still looking for an answer but here is what I did and it was much simpler than the work around they suggest.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {

            CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function (ev) {
                var bodyelement = ev.editor.document.$.body;
                bodyelement.setAttribute("contenteditable", false);


            });
            CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
        };

    </script>
```

Comment: also I noticed that the format buttons are still enabled when you use the script I posted above so you might want to change the toolbar... 'CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',{toolbar:[["Print","-","About"]]}' ... that is freehanded so double check the toolbar custom syntax before implementing

Answer (score 2):

Check [this CKEditor forum entry](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15659) where the issue is discussed, and a CKEditor team member provides a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

An important update to this thread, as of 3.6 this is supported by:
http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setReadOnly