# customize editor

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, html

Q:

I use FckEditor in my page..

http://ckeditor.com/download

at some point ,, i need to make this editor readonly..

in .cs but i don't know how to do this ,, is that impossible to find another control instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this thread : [Disabling CKEditor, Re-enabling with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943210/disabiling-ckeditor-re-enabling-with-js)